# "Linker command failed with exit code 1" message when building project after adding RMQClient framework to XCODe 7.3 Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7, rmq

I am trying to add `RMQClient framework` to my `XCODE 7.3` project.
I am following the steps as specified in https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client as well as in the `RabbitMQ` official site.

After adding the framework and running `Tools->Build` I am receiving

```
ld: framework not found RMQClient
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Error messages and can't import any of the header files from the framework.
Any suggestions for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Copying the framework package to the Project tree on Xcode solved the problem.
remember to make sure the framework is also linked and files are copied in the Build Phases section